# How do I get the data published at client-side's subscribe method on Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, websocket, publish, publish-subscribe

I want to send a message from Server to client to specific "channels"/"subjects".

So I thought the right way of doing it was using the `Publish/Subscribe` feature.

But there's something I'm missing:

How do I handle the messages sent by the server? All the examples are like this in client-side:

```
Meteor.subscribe('todos.inList', list._id);
```

What is this method doing? How do I get the data published?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I handle the messages sent by the server?

Subscribe to the publication(explaining later) and you will get access to the collection that are published by the server. Then you can execute queries on those collections.

> How do I get the data published?

You can publish one or more collections to with `Publication`. You can publish the todo list of any given user by following publication:

```
Meteor.publish('users.todoList', function (userId) {
    return TodoList.find({'userId': userId});
}
```

Comment: publish is on server. I mean how do I get the data in the client. 
the only way of doing it is by changing the database??

Comment: When you publish data from server you will get it in the client end by subscribing to that publication. You don't need to take any extra measure for that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above.another approach is to use MeteorObservable

https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/MeteorObservable